# MySQL - InnoDB, cache a part of a query for faster execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, caching, innodb

I have about 4 tables, one of them is about 10 millions rows ( it increase to about 500k lines per month ), the tables are fully optimized, my query is like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(id), select... FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on ...,
INNER JOIN table3 on ...
INNER JOIN table 4 on...
WHERE [ different conditions every time ]
```

This query takes about 1 minute execution time ( wich is far too long ) and what I want is to cache the first part of the query ( all but not the `WHERE` ) and then, once the cache is done, apply the where to the query cached.

The general idea is to execute the first part of the query every morning ( for exemple ) to put in cache this query to have minimal execution time when users will execute their own queries ( with the `WHERE` clause )

I think its possible because I tried for 'bechnmarking' to execute the query without WHERE ( about 1 minute execution time ), then I ran it with the WHERE clause and got a very low execution time so I think it seems working.

But I need help at this point, I dont know how to increase performances, how to put in the cache the query without the `where` or if you have a better solution...

Thank you in advance for your attention

Comment: If you provide the real query, schema, and more information about your data, we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can prepare [Materialized view](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) for this query

> WHAT IS A MATERIALIZED VIEW?
>   A Materialized View (MV) is the pre-calculated (materialized) result of a query. Unlike a simple VIEW the result of a Materialized View is stored somewhere, generally in a table. Materialized Views are used when immediate response is needed and the query where the Materialized View bases on would take to long to produce a result. Materialized Views have to be refreshed once in a while. It depends on the requirements how often a Materialized View is refreshed and how actual its content is. Basically a Materialized View can be refreshed immediately or deferred, it can be refreshed fully or to a certain point in time. MySQL does not provide Materialized Views by itself. But it is easy to build Materialized Views yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For query cache to work, queries must match exactly. Consider creating a table, complete with indexes, then insert data from the first query with `INSERT ... SELECT`, then use that table.

You could also use `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` to make the table the first time.